# IPhone SDK : Start my application from scratch when launched again

Tags: iphone, ios4

Here are my issues,

When I install my application on my test device it has the behaviour I want.

However if I close it with the IPhone main button and restart with the icon, it starts back from the view where I left it, whereas I would like it to restart from my main view controller (my start view).

In the same way, I load some animations with viewDidLoad in certain views. I want them to show only the first time the view is loaded each time the application is launched. Right now animations only works the first time the application is launched after installation, then they don't screen anymore when I launch again the application.

Does anyone have a clue ?

Thank you very much for your help.

(Sorry if this topic is a bit easy for you guys :D, I'm quite new at it !)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No problem about being new! This is happening because, for devices from iOS 4.0 on up, your app will support multitasking by default. To disable this features, Add the key

```
UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend
```

to your `Info.plist` file, and set its value to `YES`. Good luck!

Comment: Great! If this answers your question, would you mind hitting the check to the left of it? Good luck with the iPhone development :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Sam's answer above, you can also add a key named:

`Application does not run in background` and set the value to `YES`.

Both work fine, however.

Comment: These are actually the same key! If you right click inside the plist, you can toggle "Show Raw Keys/Values" to switch between raws key and descriptions.

Comment: Huh, never knew that!  Thanks! :)